Hosting two websites on the same server using Nginx, Grav and Wordpress in docker
I am trying to host both my own website (Grav + Nginx) and a friend's Wordpress website (Wordpress + Nginx in a docker container) on the same Ubuntu server. I have been using the following resources to set this up:

Digital Ocean tutorial for setting up WP with Docker
A post I made on the Grav forum

I'm having some trouble understanding how I should setup nginx however. Currently I have two instances of Nginx, one in a docker container and one not, and they clash, producing the following error message when I try to start the docker image:
$ docker compose up -d

WARN[0000] docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete 
[+] Running 2/3
 ✔ Container db         Running                                                                                       0.0s 
 ✔ Container wordpress  Running                                                                                       0.0s 
 ⠹ Container webserver  Starting                                                                                      0.2s 
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (375f0e4fc971481f546a1f6f5a0630190e2a19cab16404fa0d714c2b0ae81aa7): failed to bind port 0.0.0.0:80/tcp: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use


I'm thinking that I just need one instance of Nginx outside the docker container which then forwards calls to the docker container, but I'm not sure.
Thoughts? Tips? Any help would be very welcome, thank you.
PS I wasn't sure whether to ask this question here, in Super User or Server Fault. Please direct me to a more appropriate Stack Exchange if this question is off topic here.

In what way do they clash? Are they trying to serve on the same port?

Yes, since I followed the Digital Ocean tutorial exactly and so the docker image and the Nginx instance inside listens to ports 80/443, just as the Nginx instance outside the image listens to ports 80/443. I've updated the post with the specific error that I get when I start up the docker image.
